# Do I need to have receptacles that I added tested before selling my home?

Tags: electrical, wiring

In my house in Cambridgeshire England I added 2 sockets to front room and bedroom the sockets was added into the ring main. This was done 10 years ago.

Now that I am selling my house, do I need to get the sockets checked or get and electrical test done? Do I need to notify the buyers of this?

Comment: Where are you/your house? The answer is going to very much depend on that.

Comment: Cambridgeshire england

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the regulations have changed in the two years since I last sold a house...

No, the work you describe - provided it is indoors - is too minor to require certification.

The buyer's surveyor may make a comment in his survey report that the wiring hasn't been tested for at least 10 years.  That might also appear in the legal Seller's Pack.  This could result in the buyer requesting a test, but that is down to them.

My understanding is that Scottish law is different.

Comment: hi thanks , do I have to inform the buyers solicitor that this work has been done.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

There will be a question in the seller's property information form about any work done. You **must** declare the work done, as the buyer will rely on the statements in that form, but can answer "two sockets added. Not notifiable under Part P of the Building Regulations. No certificates held".